# How to capture the output of a cmd window spawned by another cmd window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd

First `cmd` window: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dihjW.png]

`hg.exe` (Mercurial) must be "Run as Administrator" (a quirk in communicating with `pageant.exe` – version and firewall issues ruled out), and thus spawns a new `cmd` window for itself.

Second `cmd` window: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEAX6.png]

But for a well-timed screenshot, there seems to be no way to capture the verbose output of the second `cmd` window as it is transient and closes as soon as `hg.exe` terminates.

I have already tried the following approaches:

1. Piping to `clip`:

   `hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld | clip`
2. Redirecting to file:

   `hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld > D:\log.txt`
3. The `cmd /k` switch:

   `cmd /k "hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld"`

Needless to say, all efforts have been in vain.

Is there a way this can be achieved?
I'm open to workarounds involving batch files and PowerShell, but a native command-line solution would be preferred.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know which streams it writes the "verbose" output to, but you might want to look into more complex stream redirection than just redirecting the standard output stream. I suggest reading the [Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) article at TechNet. [PowerShell uses stream 4 for verbose output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx), but I don't know if that's what `hg.exe` does. There's probably some 'standard' for the verbose stream number, so I suggest trying 4; otherwise 3-9 are all "specific to each tool".

Comment: Consider running the entire script elevated rather than elevating just the `hg` command.  You can create a shortcut to the script and give it the "run as administrator" setting.

Comment: @robert.westerlund: note that the additional streams (3-9) provided by `cmd.exe` are only available within a single `cmd.exe` process, not to subprocesses or subshells.  The additional PowerShell streams are probably similar.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I should have mentioned that I have had to resort to that in the time being. I would prefer to operate from an unelevated `cmd`, but maybe I'm asking too much of Windows. Aside from that and the `elevate` PowerToy, there seems to be no other solution, as your latter comment illuminates.

Comment: @robert.westerlund I should also have mentioned that the verbosity stems from my use of the `-v` flag in `ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -batch -C -v` in `mercurial.ini`. I provide this additional information to clarify that the verbose output presents itself normally in an elevated `cmd` window. As I could not find anything relevant in the Mercurial documentation, is there a way to identify which stream it might be sent to when invoked without the verbose flag?

Comment: There are only two output streams, stdout and stderr.  The problem is simply that you can't launch a process elevated and redirect its output in a single operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you can't both elevate and redirect output in a single operation.

The usual solution is to elevate the entire script, which also has the advantage that the user only has to confirm elevation once rather than each time you call an elevated command.  There isn't *usually* any reason not to do this.

However, another approach would be to create a shortcut with target `cmd.exe /c` and the "Run as administrator" option set.  Supposing we name it `elevation.lnk` you could launch it like this:

```
start /wait elevation.lnk "hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld | clip"
```

That approach won't preserve the current directory; if this is necessary, use

```
start /wait elevation.lnk "cd /d %cd% && hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld | clip"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to begin with: it redirects STDERR to the file too, as some tools write their messages there.

```
hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/slaiyer/hellwrld > D:\log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: As a test: If you actually open a cmd prompt with admin perms and launch it, does it then still open a new window?

Comment: No, it does not. I have had to resort to that in the time being. I would prefer to operate from an unelevated `cmd`, but maybe I'm asking too much of Windows. Aside from that and the `elevate` PowerToy, there seems to be no other solution as of now.